# Upgrade to 2.2.6 missing static JS files

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2.2.6, static-content, static-content-deploy

When I upgraded my Magento 2.2.2 to 2.2.6.

I got one critical error in `pub/static` missing one file named `trim-input.js`

> "pub/static/version1540806968/frontend/{...}/{...}/pl_PL/mage/trim-input.js"

I try add this to `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'trimInput': 'mage/trim-input'
        }
    },
};
```

How can I add this to static content?

I cant add it in `pub/static/...` because after `bin/console exec setup:static-content:deploy -f` file was deleted.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this as I now have the same issue

Comment: Yes you  need to

-add or edit: 
app/design/frontend/{...}/{...}/requirejs-config.js 

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'trimInput': 'mage/trim-input'
        }
    },
};

-and add: 
app/design/frontend/{...}/{...}/web/mage/trim-input.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file exists in:

```
lib/mage/trim-input.js
```

If the file is not there, it won't be copied over into `pub/static`